# Как привязать @RequestParam к обьекту?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

При передаче в метод использую много "@RequestParam"
Как я понял спринг может собрать эти параметры в обьект при наличии сеттеров
но также я передаю токен в запросе
Вопрос -- есть ли возможность указать только 2 "@RequestParam"(один для обьекта, второй для токена)?

**ВМЕСТО**

```
public ResponseEntity<Coupon> editCoupon(@RequestParam int id,
                                        @RequestParam int amount,
                                        @RequestParam int category,
                                        @RequestParam String description,
                                        @RequestParam String imgUrl,
                                        @RequestParam double price,
                                        @RequestParam String title,
                                        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
                                        @RequestParam LocalDateTime startDate,
                                        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
                                        @RequestParam LocalDateTime endDate,
                                        @RequestParam String token) {
```

**КАК-ТО ТАК**

```
public ResponseEntity<Coupon> editCoupon(@RequestParam Coupon coupon,
                                         @RequestParam String token) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо убрать аннотацию `RequestParam`. `Spring` автоматически заполнит параметрами запроса экземпляр класса `Coupon`.

```
public ResponseEntity<Coupon> editCoupon(
        Coupon coupon,
        @RequestParam String token) {
    ...
}
```